# How to get circle in different color CalendarView

Tags: android, calendarview

How to get the circle in current date like we get in when we select any date in Calendar View just like that I need circle in different color to indicate the current date if user didn't select the current date if user select current date back to selected circle color and user select any other date then current date circle should change how I can get it.

Below is my code:

```
<CalendarView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/CalenderViewCustom"
            android:weekDayTextAppearance="@style/CalenderViewWeekCustomText" />

<style name="CalenderViewCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">#268FBB</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="CalenderViewDateCustomText" parent="android:TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="CalenderViewWeekCustomText" parent="android:TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```